# Conditionally Displaying EJS data

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

I am trying to reuse a a view in EJS. It just creates a list of the results of a database query. My code is

```
   <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="a">
    <% for(var i=0; i<records.length; i++) { %>
        <li><a href="#actions" onClick="SetCurrentCustomer(<%= records[i].ID %>)">
PROBLEM HERE---->    <%= records[i].Name %> <%= records[i].TOJ%></a></li>
    <% } %>
    </ul>
```

I would only like to show each records[i].Name and records[i].TOJ if they are defined or if the view is called from a certain route or whatever is easier. I have tried inserting a function to filter, but it just got ignored. How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like `for`, you can also use `if` in EJS:

```
<% if (someCondition) { %>
  <%= records[i].Name %> <%= records[i].TOJ %>
<% }; %>
```

Or, if you just want to prevent `undefined` being shown when a property isn't defined, you can use this:

```
<%= records[i].Name || '' %> <%= records[i].TOJ || '' %>
```

(be aware that this would fail for properties containing the number `0` or a boolean `false`)

Comment: exactly what I needed. Thanks robertklep!

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for.

Comment: Perfect, what if you wanted to trigger a jquery function if `records.length > 0` ?

Comment: @Cmag you could insert a `<script>` block that calls the jQuery function.